# Extract object with same key from multiple array and make them into one array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array of `widgets` containing multiple objects. Each object contains an array called `cards` which contains just a single object. I need help with extracting all the `cards` object and making a new `cards` array containing all the cards as elements

```
{
    "widgets" : [
        {
            "type": "Grid",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Grid",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How I want is

```
{
    "widgets": [
        {
            "type": "Grid",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                },
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us a [mcve] so we can help you

Comment: looks like a group by problem. something that can be done similarly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72621887/group-similar-key-value-pair-to-a-single-array/72622005#72622005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the original object `orig` and extract it's `cards` into a new array `allCards`:

```
const allCards = [];
for (let widget of orig.widgets) {
    allCards.push(widget.cards[0]); 
}
```

Then you can construct a new object with these extracted cards.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement, the below might work.

```
let x = {
    "widgets" : [
        {
            "type": "Grid",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Grid",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
let y = {"widgets": [{...x.widgets[0], "cards":[]}]};
x.widgets.forEach(el => y.widgets[0].cards.push(...[].concat(el.cards)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code that taek into account the type of each widget :

```js
object = {
    "widgets" : [
        {
            "type": "Grid",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Grid",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Table",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Grid",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "data": {},
                    "layout": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

new_object = {"widgets" : []}

for (let i=0;  i < object["widgets"].length; i++) {
    exist = false
    for (let j=0;  j < new_object["widgets"].length; j++) {
        if (new_object["widgets"][j]["type"] === object["widgets"][i]["type"]){
            exist = true
            new_object["widgets"][j]["cards"].push(object["widgets"][i]["cards"][0])
        }
    }
    if (exist === false){
        new_object["widgets"].push(object["widgets"][i])
    }
  
}
console.log(new_object)
```